# router-outlet inside router-outlet calling independent routes dynamically

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular2-services

I have angular 2 project that has many modules in it. I load each of the module using lazy loading technique as follows

```
{ path: 'home', loadChildren: './dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule' },
```

Now I have a situation where I load a module called `WorkflowManagementModule` using

```
{ path: 'workflow', loadChildren: './workflow-management/workflow-management.module#WorkflowManagementModule' },
```

In the workflow module I have a component called workflow-footer that is just a footer with button with label next. When I click next a rest call will be made to the server and the a field "url" will be received from the server. On receiving this I have to navigate to that url.

Now the **problem** is

I have to have the footer component footer of the loaded routes. I.e. the new component (based on the route received from server) component has to be loaded and it should have the footer as workflow-footer component.as shown below

[image]

This is the situation as below in the code

```
<div>some other content</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<work-footer></work-footer>
```

But I can't understanding how achieve this as the routes are not constant ,it can be dynamic depending on the server response.As well as it is in other module.So please help me to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not certain I understand. Are you trying to specify entirely different footer content based on the route?

If so, then add the appropriate footer component onto the template for each routed component.

In Component A:

```
<div>Component A Stuff</div>
<compA-footer></compA-footer>
```

OR

Are you saying that you want to route different things into the footer area? If so, then you can use a named router outlet.

```
<div>some other content</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="footer"></router-outlet>
```

Then you can navigate some content into the first router outlet and different content into the named router outlet.

OR

If you want to have a standard footer that appears below multiple pages, you can use the technique you specified in your question:

```
<div>some other content</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<work-footer></work-footer>
```

Is that not working for you?

Comment: No..I want to navigate to multiple url one after the other with same footer component as the footer .Basically i have a "next" button in the footer which changes the routes.

Comment: Then the code you specified should work. See my addition above.

Comment: But this router-outlet is inside another routeroutlet.If i navigate,it completely reloads the page with new route

Comment: Router outlets can be within other router outlets. I have several examples of this and it does *not* reload the page. Could you provide a simple plunker that demonstrates your issues and we can take a look?